# convert Time "HH:mm:ss.000Z" from Time "HH:mm:ss"

Tags: java, time

I am developing one Java application and getting data from webservice with parameter Time "HH:mm:ss.000Z" format.

How do I convert Time "HH:mm:ss.000Z" from Time "HH:mm:ss" format using below line but getting same error for time.

There is auto generated code from wsdl.

```
org.apache.axis.types.Time time=new org.apache.axis.types.Time("00:00:01");
```

Comment: "but getting error" doesn't give us *nearly* enough information. A compile-time error? An exception at execution time? Just the wrong data? Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-list

Comment: what is the error? Is it NumberFormatException thrown? Paste the error message here.

Answer (score 0):

Check implementation of class Time.

```
 private static SimpleDateFormat zulu =
       new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
```

This is SimpleDateFormat used by Time class to convert time to that format.